# Getting module not found error when using firebase with nextjs

Tags: firebase, next.js

I recently upgraded to using the app router in my app. However each time i try to run `next dev` im running into `Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in 'C:\Users\HP\projects\project-webtechafrica\client\node_modules\@firebase\auth\node_modules\node-fetch\lib'`

I don`t know what it is im doing wrong.

Here is the full console error

```
- warn ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in 'C:\Users\HP\projects\project-webtechafrica\client\node_modules\@firebase\auth\node_modules\node-fetch\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index.js
./node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/index.mjs
./hooks/useAuth.tsx

./node_modules/@firebase/storage/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in 'C:\Users\HP\projects\project-webtechafrica\client\node_modules\@firebase\storage\node_modules\node-fetch\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@firebase/storage/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js
./node_modules/firebase/storage/dist/index.mjs
./firebase/firebase.ts
./hooks/useAuth.tsx
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling firebase and node-fetch. I dont really use node-fetch but i was just throwing curveballs at the error. That didnt fix it. Im not sure if its because i created context hooks and wrapped them around the main layout.tsx.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} relative`}>
        <GlobalDataProvider>
          <AuthContextProvider>
            <SelectionsProvider>
              <Navbar />
              {children}
              <Footer />
            </SelectionsProvider>
          </AuthContextProvider>
        </GlobalDataProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Here is part of the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@formspree/react": "^2.4.2",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
"@google-pay/button-react": "^3.0.9",
"@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^8.0.0",
"@types/node": "20.3.1",
"@types/react": "18.2.12",
"@types/react-dom": "18.2.5",
"autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"eslint": "8.43.0",
"eslint-config-next": "13.4.6",
"firebase": "^10.1.0",
"framer-motion": "^10.15.1",
"fs": "^0.0.1-security",
"glob": "^10.3.0",
"globby": "^13.2.0",
"next": "^13.4.13",
"node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
"openai": "^3.3.0",
"postcss": "8.4.24",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.45.0",
"sharp": "^0.32.1",
"tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
"typeface-nunito": "^1.1.13",
"typeface-playfair-display": "^1.1.13",
"typescript": "5.1.3",
"uid": "^2.0.2"
```

}

Please help.

Comment: You should edit the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` sections of your `package.json` file into question to help other users reproduce your install.

Comment: @samthecodingman im going to do that right now.